# around which points in a spherical coordinate transformation is a space invertible?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis, inverse

For the question below, I have read the wolfram article which restricts all three points based on the representation s cartesian coordinates.  For example, $r\in[0,\infty]$.  But how would I then find express all points so that the space near them is invertible?

> Near which points $(r, \phi, \theta)$ is the following spherical coordinate transformation in space invertible?
>
> $x=r\cos\phi \sin\theta$
>   $y=r\sin\phi \sin\theta$
>
> $z=r\cos\theta$

Comment: $(0,\theta, \phi)$ are all mapped to $(0,0,0)$

Comment: I have edited the question.  I realized after reading the wolfram article on the topic that I was going about it the wrong way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Jacobian-determinant of the transformation is $\sin(\theta)r^2$. If this is non-zero the transformation is invertible in a neighbourhood of that point. Thus the only possible exceptions are points that solve $\sin(\theta)r^2=0$. And thus $r=0$ or $\theta= \pi p$, $p\in \mathbb Z$ (regardless of the values of the remaining coordinates) are the exceptions - and indeed the transformation isn't invertible at those points. To see this note that $(r,\theta, \phi)=(0,\theta, \phi)$ all maps to $(0,0,0)$, $(r,\theta, \phi)=(r,2\pi p,\phi)$ all maps to $(0,0,r)$, $(r,\theta, \phi)=(r,\pi ,\phi)=(r,3\pi,\phi)$ all maps to $(0,0,-r)$.

**EDIT:**

The determinant is the determinant of:
$$
 \begin{pmatrix}
 \partial_r x & \partial_\theta x & \partial_\phi x\\
\partial_r y & \partial_\theta y & \partial_\phi y\\
\partial_r z & \partial_\theta z & \partial_\phi z
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: How did you find the determinant of the transformation?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!  I should've instantly converted the transformation into a matrix and that would've made my life easier